# The result from autocomplete are not displayed in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, partial

I am using an ASP.NET MVC web site written in C#. I have code for an autocomplete that works fine in a regular view but not in a partial view. In the partial view,the results are sent back from the controller and the data is there but it is not displayed for the text box in the partial view.

The following is the Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchBox1").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                //alert(request.term);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/MArrangement/EventDetailAutoView",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                          //alert(item.CityName);  
return { label: item.CityName, value: item.CityId };
                        }))

                    }
                })

            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert('1a');
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('2b');
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            messages: {

                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
    });
});
```

This is the partial view:

```
<div>
    <label>Search by Item or Inventory Type</label><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.City.CityName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "SearchBox1", style = "position:absolute; z-index:11" } })
</div>
```

This is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EventDetailAutoView(string Prefix)
{
        List<Models.City> ObjList = new List<City>();
        Models.Mod.InventoryMain.getInventory(ref ObjList, Guid.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString()));
        var CityList = (from N in ObjList
                        where N.CityName.ToLower().Contains(Prefix.ToLower())
                        select new { N.CityName, N.CityId }).ToList();
        return Json(CityList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The method `EventDetailAutoView` is being called and is returning the correct data. In the success portion of the Javascript code, the data is shown (I put in a alert statement to see the data) but the results are not displayed underneath the SearchBox1 text box. The following code works fine in a regular view but not in a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You should add same code in regular view once partial view loads successfully.

[image]

```
var strUrDomainNamel =  + '/Controller/Method';
        $.ajax({
            url: strUrl,
            cache: false,
            data: {},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".partialLoadview").html(data);
                $("#SearchBox1").autocomplete({
                    //Your code for autocomplete must be here. 
                });
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert('error message');
             }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks? let me check that out.